# Doesn't write setup next to windows

Tags: dual-boot

No matter where I searched, I couldn't find the solution. While allocating disk, I reserved 40gb in windows. but when i come to ubuntu installation it says unusable.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kJjR.jpg)

Comment: If your partition table is *legacy* or MBR, then there is only room for a maximum of four primary partitions. No OS can overrule what will fit given only four entries exist. If you partition table is of that type, the only fix is to remove one of the existing partitions (meaning an empty table entry exists) or re-create the layout so it uses secondary partitions (not all primary).  *The newer GPT partition table was created to get around this issue as four primary was a hard-limit that can't be changed; users/operators were intended to plan ahead & not hit four primary on initial setup*

Comment: guiverc, my disk is ssd but mbr. Windows has 531mb recovery on disk. Do you mind if I delete it?

Comment: Ubuntu won't care if you delete a windows partition; whether or not windows requires it relates to a number of windows details which are off-topic on this Ubuntu site.  The type of drive doesn't matter though; it's the partition table put on the drive (*be it mechanical, solid-state, flash media or something else*)